# How to add a trash icon to the Gnome 3 favorites?

Tags: gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell

I'd like to add a trash icon to the Gnome 3 favorites vertical bar on the left of the desktop.

Comment: @don_crissti ah indeed, that's obvious! thanks. But still, I want the trash icon, etc. Would be fine if anyone provided a template of these settings.

Comment: @don_crissti thanks... such `.desktop` template could be an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make your own launcher e.g. `trashcan.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Trash Can Viewer
Comment=Because I Can!
Exec=gvfs-open trash:///
Icon=user-trash
Terminal=false
Categories=GNOME;
```

place it<sup>1</sup> in `$XDG_DATA_HOME/applications` (usually `~/.local/share/applications`) if you intent it to be user-specific or in`$XDG_DATA_DIR/applications` (usually `/usr/share/applications`) if you want it to be available to all users; then, while in overview mode, click on the *Show Applications* button on the *dash* (or use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>), find the trash icon and just drag it to *dash* (favourites).

---

1: Note that on some setups the desktop file has to be "marked as trusted" (either double click it and *Mark As Trusted* or make it executable and add `#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open` at the top of the file).

Comment: Thanks.... but still, a static icon is not a proper trashcan! =) When there's trash inside it it shouldn't use the same empty trashcan icon.